# Equivalent to balancer, broadcast and merge in pure akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

In akka streams, using  graph dsl builder i can use balancer, broadcast and merger operators:

```scala
Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
 val balancer = builder.add(Balance[Result1](2))
 val merger = builder.add(Merge[Result2](2))

 balancer.out(0) ~> step1.async ~> step2.async ~> merger.in(0)
 balancer.out(1) ~> step1.async ~> step2.async ~> merger.in(1)

 FlowShape(balancer.in, merger.out)
}
```

How i can achieve the same logic using plain Source, Sink and Flow api?

I can do something like this:

```scala
source.mapAsync(2)(Future(...))
```

But, as i see, semanticlly it is not fully equivalent to the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Source.combine` and `Sink.combine`. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-graphs.html#combining-sources-and-sinks-with-simplified-api):

> There is a simplified API you can use to combine sources and sinks with junctions like: `Broadcast[T]`, `Balance[T]`, `Merge[In]` and `Concat[A]` without the need for using the Graph DSL. The combine method takes care of constructing the necessary graph underneath. In following example we combine two sources into one (fan-in):

```
val sourceOne = Source(List(1))
val sourceTwo = Source(List(2))
val merged = Source.combine(sourceOne, sourceTwo)(Merge(_))

val mergedResult: Future[Int] = merged.runWith(Sink.fold(0)(_ + _))
```

> The same can be done for a `Sink[T]` but in this case it will be fan-out:

```
val sendRmotely = Sink.actorRef(actorRef, "Done")
val localProcessing = Sink.foreach[Int](_ => /* do something useful */ ())

val sink = Sink.combine(sendRmotely, localProcessing)(Broadcast[Int](_))

Source(List(0, 1, 2)).runWith(sink)
```